# Accessing Model Data in Template

Tags: ember.js

I have a route defined like so:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('games', function() {
        this.route('game', {path: '/:game_id'}, function() {});
    });
});
```

When I visit path `/games/1` I have to access the model data like so:

```
{{model.title}}
```

Reading the documentation, it seems that the controller would make the model data available without the model prefix so I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
{{title}}
```

But it doesn't work without `model`. I'm not creating the controller because I don't need to extend it for this particular route/template. Is accessing the model data via the `model` prefix accurate? Or am I possibly doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs you are referring to are old, in the past (pre 1.13 iirc) the controller had a model proxy that would look up properties on the model if they weren't found on the controller.

This is no longer available since it was causing confusion in the community.

The new versions of the [docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/controllers/) no longer reference `{{title}}` without `model`.

If you really want to use it without the `model` prefix you could resort to [Ember.computed.alias](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_alias) though I would recommend sticking with `model.` as it is easier to read and identify as a model property vs controller property, especially since routable components are set to replace controllers in the near future (~2.6).

Comment: Perfect. I don't mind using model. I just wanted to make sure I was doing it correctly. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `{{model.title}}` or `{{content.title}}`. Earlier it possible to access properties directly using [ObjectControllers](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller) but now as those are gone there is no other way.

[Edits]

There is one more way, you can extend `setupController` in route and set title on controller itself. That way you'll be able to directly use `{{title}}`.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
   this._super(controller, model);
   controller.set('title', model.get('title'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to do this in the `setupController` a computed property on the controller with a dependent key of `model.title` is more of the place for such a thing

Comment: @Kitler OP has mentioned in the question that he doesn't want to create controller. So implementing `setupController` is the best way to go in my opinion.

Comment: He does realize that the controller is auto generated right?

Comment: I hope so. But I think controller will be autogenerated at runtime but not in the code.

Comment: It seems the OP is following some really old tutorials/references, his remaining questions are full of deprecated/discontinued features.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember, your model must be loaded by a route as described in the documentation [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

Assuming you are using ember-cli your route will look like :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     // Must return some data or promises
    }
});
```

Model function can either return an array of data or a promises that will resolve to an array.
If you are using ember-data your function return will look like this :

```
return this.store.find('game', params.game_id);
```

You can also request directly to an API :

```
return Ember.$.getJSON('https://your-website.com/game/' + params.game_id);
```